# How implement custom chrono::clock with own tick source

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm trying to create a own custom chrono clock to control the tick counter for simulation. So I can stop/resume the clock or control speed of the clock.

My custom clock with a own tick counter is not working in wait_until (e.g condition_variable) functions with a Predicate.

When call a wait_until without a Predicate it works (may be not as designed) but the result is OK.
In the wait_until function the myClock::now() function is polled until the timeout is reached or the condition_variable is notified.

With a Predicate the wait_until function returns always that a timeout occurs. See code and output.

Is it possible to implement a clock like I want to control the tick?

A non steady clock has the same result.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

// data for conditional variable inclusive dataReady flag to prevent for spurious wakeup
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;
std::atomic<bool> dataReady{ false };
void setDataReady()
{
   {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(cv_m);
      dataReady.store(true);
   }
   cv.notify_one();
}
void blockData()
{
   {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(cv_m);
      dataReady.store(false);
   }
}


std::atomic<uint64_t> tickCounter{ 0 };
struct my_steady_clock 
{
   using rep = long long;
   using period = milli;
   using duration = chrono::milliseconds;
   using time_point = chrono::time_point<my_steady_clock>;
   static constexpr bool is_steady = true;

   static time_point now() noexcept 
   { 
      cout << "call now() tick is: " << tickCounter << "\n";
      return time_point
      (
         chrono::duration_cast<duration>(chrono::milliseconds(tickCounter))
      );
   }
   static void addTick() noexcept
   {
      tickCounter++;
      cout << "call addTick new tick:" << tickCounter << "\n";
   }
   static uint64_t getTick() noexcept
   {
      return tickCounter;
   }
};

void waits_pred(const chrono::milliseconds& dur)
{
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
   auto now = my_steady_clock::now() + dur;

   if (cv.wait_until(lk, now, [] { return dataReady.load(); }))
      std::cerr << "Thread with duration " << dur << " finished waiting. " << " DataReady is: " << dataReady.load() << '\n';
   else
      std::cerr << "Thread with duration " << dur << " timed out. dataReady is: " << dataReady.load() << '\n';
   lk.unlock();
}

void waits(const chrono::milliseconds& dur)
{
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
   auto now = my_steady_clock::now() + dur;

   if (std::cv_status::no_timeout == cv.wait_until(lk, now))
      std::cerr << "Thread duration " << dur << " finished waiting. " << '\n';
   else
      std::cerr << "Thread duration " << dur << " timed out. " << '\n';
   lk.unlock();
}


int main() 
{
   std::cout << "----- wait thread with duration --------------" << '\n' << '\n';

   std::cout << '\n' << "----- start thread 1 waits without Predicate --------------" << '\n';
   std::thread thr1(waits, 10ms);

   // wait 8 ticks and then notify must wakeup thread
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
   {
      // wait some time to compare if own clock tick is used for waiting not system clock
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
      my_steady_clock::addTick();
   }
   setDataReady();
   thr1.join();
   blockData();

   // set tick counter back, easier to read output
   tickCounter.store(0);
   std::cout << '\n' << "----- start thread 2 waits with Predicate --------------" << '\n';
   std::thread thr2(waits_pred, 11ms);

   // wait 8 ticks and then notify must wakeup thread
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
   {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
      my_steady_clock::addTick();
   }
   setDataReady();
   thr2.join();
   blockData();

   // set tick counter back, easier to read output
   tickCounter.store(0);
   std::cout << '\n' << "----- start thread 3 waits with Predicate --------------" << '\n';
   std::thread thr3(waits_pred, 12ms);

   // wait 10 ticks and then thread must wakeup because of timeout
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
   {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
      my_steady_clock::addTick();
   }
   thr3.join();
}
```

Output with comments (<--) is:

```
----- wait thread with duration --------------


----- start thread 1 waits without Predicate --------------
call now() tick is: 0
call now() tick is: 0
call now() tick is: 0
call now() tick is: 0
call now() tick is: 0
call now() tick is: 0
call now() tick is: 0
call addTick new tick:1
call now() tick is: 1
call now() tick is: 1
call now() tick is: 1
call now() tick is: 1
call now() tick is: 1
call now() tick is: 1
call now() tick is: 1
call addTick new tick:2
call now() tick is: 2
call now() tick is: 2
call now() tick is: 2
call now() tick is: 2
call now() tick is: 2
call now() tick is: 2
call now() tick is: 2
call addTick new tick:3
call now() tick is: 3
call now() tick is: 3
call now() tick is: 3
call now() tick is: 3
call now() tick is: 3
call now() tick is: 3
call now() tick is: 3
call addTick new tick:4
call now() tick is: 4
call now() tick is: 4
call now() tick is: 4
call now() tick is: 4
call now() tick is: 4
call now() tick is: 4
call now() tick is: 4
call addTick new tick:5
call now() tick is: 5
call now() tick is: 5
call now() tick is: 5
call now() tick is: 5
call now() tick is: 5
call now() tick is: 5
call now() tick is: 5
call now() tick is: 6
call addTick new tick:6
call now() tick is: 6
call now() tick is: 6
call now() tick is: 6
call now() tick is: 6
call now() tick is: 6
call now() tick is: 6
call addTick new tick:7
call now() tick is: 7
call now() tick is: 7
call now() tick is: 7
call now() tick is: 7
call now() tick is: 7
call now() tick is: 7
call now() tick is: 7
call now() tick is: 8
call addTick new tick:8
Thread duration 10ms finished waiting.                   <-- OK, notify was called after 8 ticks

----- start thread 2 waits with Predicate --------------
call now() tick is: 0
call now() tick is: 0
Thread with duration 11ms timed out. dataReady is: 0    <-- Error, timeout 11 ms not over
call addTick new tick:1
call addTick new tick:2
call addTick new tick:3
call addTick new tick:4
call addTick new tick:5
call addTick new tick:6
call addTick new tick:7
call addTick new tick:8

----- start thread 3 waits with Predicate --------------
call now() tick is: 0
call now() tick is: 0
Thread with duration 12ms timed out. dataReady is: 0    <-- Error, timeout 12 ms not over
call addTick new tick:1
call addTick new tick:2
call addTick new tick:3
call addTick new tick:4
call addTick new tick:5
call addTick new tick:6
call addTick new tick:7
call addTick new tick:8
call addTick new tick:9
call addTick new tick:10
call addTick new tick:11
call addTick new tick:12
```

Comment: I think most implementations will just convert any provided times into whatever time is used by the OS's mutex API. E.g in [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/condition_variable#L127) it converts to system or steady clock before waiting

Comment: Your code works for me on macOS (using clang/libc++).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I build the code in linux with gcc with c++17 it works. But with c++20 I got a compile error static_assert(chrono::is_clock_v<_Clock>); Can I avoid this error?

Comment: I found the problem with the c++20 in linux. the clock declaration must be    `using duration = chrono::duration<rep, period>; 
using time_point = chrono::time_point<my_steady_clock, duration>; `